# Why is g-recaptcha not displaying in dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, recaptcha

I am trying to implement g-recaptcha in dropdown menu. I managed to display on a separate page with a form, but inside the dropdown menu it is not displayed, what could be the problem?

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="dropdown me-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-secondary dropdown-toggle " id="dropdownMenuOffset"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-offset="10,20">

        <div class="g-recaptcha form-group"
           data-sitekey="site-key">

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```